# using bash to read pdf content

Tags: bash

I have several ebooks which are not always named after the title of the book. Would it be possible to use bash commands to read the pdf's first page (and do a trivial grep etc) and rename the file accordingly ?

thanks

-a

Comment: and the negative vote goes for what exactly ???

Comment: this is not my vote but I can see that the person who voted to close the question specified the following reason for closing: _To broad, There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs_.

Comment: In addition to `pdfinfo` there's also a `pdftotext` command available, which is a more literal answer for your question -- but it's nowhere near reliable enough for the use case described. It's not mandatory for PDFs to contain characters, as opposed to graphics describing characters, so doing what you want can often mean OCR, and OCR is error-prone and unreliable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Poppler Library](http://poppler.freedesktop.org/) provides a set of command line tools to extract text and metadata from PDF files.

To extract metadata you could use `pdfinfo`

For example

```
:~> pdfinfo ProAdminGuide.pdf  2>/dev/null | \
  grep Title: | sed 's/Title:[ ]*//'
```

Outputs

```
Professional Administrator’s Guide
```

Sometimes the PDF file does not contain complete metadata. In this case you might try your luck to extract the title from the text of the title page. To extract the text of the title page you could use `pdftotext`

```
:~> pdftotext ProAdminGuide.pdf - | head -3
```

Outputs

```
A division of


Professional Administrator’s Guide, published by
```

In any case it is worth first checking that you can extract the titles from the pdf file before renaming them automatically

```
for book in *.pdf ; do 
   title=$(pdfinfo "$book" 2>/dev/null | grep Title: | sed 's/Title:[ ]*//')
   [[ "$title" ]] || continue
   mv "$book" "${title}.pdf"  
done
```

**Edit:** added a nice idiom suggested by Charles Duffy in the comments as a precaution

Comment: Perhaps you want a `[[ $title ]] || continue` in your loop, before the `mv`? It would be unfortunate to try to rename 50 files to all have the name `.pdf`.